Cassandra query for the most recent item of a particular clustering key
I'm trying to get all the file_id items for the most recent version for the specified folder_id for the example_table defined below in Cassandra. Is this possible, or is my data designed incorrectly for my use case?
example_table



folder_id (Partition Key)
file_id (Clustering Key)
version (timestamp Clustering Key) ORDER DESC




1
1
2


1
1
1


1
2
2


1
2
1


1
3
2


1
3
1



I'm thinking the query would be something like this, but I'm not able to get it working.
SELECT folder_id,file_id,MAX(version) FROM example_table WHERE folder_id=1;
desired result



folder_id (Partition Key)
file_id (Clustering Key)
version (timestampClustering Key) ORDER DESC




1
1
2


1
2
2


1
3
2




What does the schema look like? If version is part of the primary key, you may be able get the last item depending on the clustering columns order.

@stevenlacerda The schema is described in the table headers and what you're suggesting is exactly what I was trying to do.

This may not be the best performing data model as your chosen partition key of folder_id if/can grow infitely.
Instead, if you alterred the table schema like as below, it will only use the partial partition key to perform the scan within that portion of the partition key (as opposed to performing a full table-scan) when allow filtering is used,
token@cqlsh:chetctor> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example_table (
  folder_id int,
  file_id int,
  version timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY((folder_id, file_id), version)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (version DESC)
<... other table properties ...>
;

and insert a couple records as:
token@cqlsh:chetctor> insert into example_table (folder_id , file_id , version ) VALUES ( 1,1,totimestamp(now()));
token@cqlsh:chetctor> insert into example_table (folder_id , file_id , version ) VALUES ( 1,1,totimestamp(now()));
token@cqlsh:chetctor> insert into example_table (folder_id , file_id , version ) VALUES ( 1,2,totimestamp(now()));
token@cqlsh:chetctor> insert into example_table (folder_id , file_id , version ) VALUES ( 1,2,totimestamp(now()));
token@cqlsh:chetctor> insert into example_table (folder_id , file_id , version ) VALUES ( 1,3,totimestamp(now()));
token@cqlsh:chetctor> insert into example_table (folder_id , file_id , version ) VALUES ( 1,3,totimestamp(now()));
token@cqlsh:chetctor> select * from example_table ;

 folder_id | file_id | version
-----------+---------+---------------------------------
         1 |       3 | 2024-12-30 15:55:05.565000+0000
         1 |       3 | 2024-12-30 15:54:59.680000+0000
         1 |       2 | 2024-12-30 15:54:53.628000+0000
         1 |       2 | 2024-12-30 15:54:51.540000+0000
         1 |       1 | 2024-12-30 15:54:45.544000+0000
         1 |       1 | 2024-12-30 15:54:34.793000+0000

(6 rows)

While using ALLOW FILTERING is always the bad choice, it may be okay here if we're querying by the partial partition key of folder_id.
token@cqlsh:chetctor> select * from example_table where folder_id=1 per PARTITION LIMIT 1 allow FILTERING ;

 folder_id | file_id | version
-----------+---------+---------------------------------
         1 |       3 | 2024-12-30 15:55:05.565000+0000
         1 |       2 | 2024-12-30 15:54:53.628000+0000
         1 |       1 | 2024-12-30 15:54:45.544000+0000

(3 rows)

This will get us all the latest file_id's (based on the version timestamp value) for the given folder_id of 1. I hope this helps you.
References to read:

PER PARTITON LIMIT

another better reference here



p/s: I've used DataStax Astra DB's CQL Console as a reference here to demonstrate the above and for full disclosure I am an employee at DataStax (as of this writing).

I appreciate the answer! But wouldn't that create a bunch of very small partitions? In my example, each partition would have exactly 2 items in it (the count of version) . I'm not familiar with the efficiency of listing a large number of partitions. Would that be a problem?

To add some context to my reasoning... I was under the impression that using only folder_id as the partition key would cause all the files for a folder to be co-located on a single node and I expected that imply a faster and more efficient listing of all file_ids since it would be able to find all file_ids on one node.
